# How to hide/show divs from Tiles through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, struts2, tiles

I'm working on a JSP site that uses Struts 2 and Tiles 3, it has different tabs and each tab shows a div with a table. I need to add a tab that has 2 tables, and alternatively show one or the other depending on buttons.

Is it possible to show/hide them though JS somehow? I've been trying for a while now, and Tiles does not seem to care to what I do from JS.

I've been using this, with some variations, but so far no luck. I'm kinda new to JS so I may be doing something wrong, or maybe Tiles has a way to hide/show stuff dynamically/during runtime that I do not know.

```js
document.getElementById('controlPools').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('controlPools').style.display='inline';
```

`controlPools` is the name of the `div`, the name of the tile that contains it is `controlPool`.

This is the code of the JSP page

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<body>

    <fieldset>
    
        <div id="controlPools">
            <display:table name="lstPools" class="displaytag" id="tablaPools" >
                                                                   
                <display:column style="width: 90%"     >
                    <a href="javascript:getNodosPool('${tablaPools.name}')" >${tablaPools.name}</a>
                </display:column>
                
                <display:column style="width: 10%" property="nodes"/>

            </display:table>
        </div>
        
        <div id="nodosPool" style="display: none;" >
            <display:table name="lstMembers" class="displaytag" id="tablaNodesPool">
                
                <display:column style="width: 5%" >
                            <input type="checkbox" id="${tablaNodesPool.name}"  class="node" value="${tablaNodesPool.name}"  style="margin: 0 0 0 4px"   />             
                         </display:column>  
                         <display:column title="Status CBS" style="width: 10%"> 
                            <div id="iconStatus"  class="${tablaNodesPool.classStatus}" /></div> 
                         </display:column>
                         
                         <display:column title="Status STF" style="width: 10%"> 
                            <div id="iconStatus"  class="${tablaNodesPool.classStatus2}" /></div> 
                         </display:column>
                                                                     
                         <display:column property="name"    />
                         <display:column property="ip"    />
                         <display:column property="description"   />

            </display:table>
            
            <button onclick="enableNodesPool();"  ><s:text name="controlSnmp.enableSelected"/></button>     
            <button onclick="disableNodesPool();" ><s:text name="controlSnmp.disableSelected"/></button>
            <button onclick="getNodosPool();"><s:text name="controlSnmp.buttonRefresh"/></button>
        </div>
        

    </fieldset>
</body>

<script>
  
</script>
```

Comment: Tiles is server-side. Without knowing anything about what your rendered HTML looks like it's impossible to provide much JS advice.

Comment: I added the JSP code, should I add the tiles config as well?

Comment: There isn't any tiles in your jsp. What exactly isn't working? Where and how do you use this js script?

Comment: I have a JS file with some functions, one of those finds the `<div>` with id nodosPool and should set it's visibility to hidden with `document.getElementById('nodosPool').style.display='none';` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Roman-C answer got me thinking, and it led me to the solution to the problem, it was partly because of tiles.

I was using this JS block to feed the data to my JSP:

```
document.getElementById('controlPools').style.display='none';
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url  : "ControlNodesPoolAct.action",
        data : {"pool": pool},
        success : function(result){
          if (result != null && result.length > 0){
            var aux = $("#tabs-11"); 
            aux.html(result);
            //inicializamos la tabla con el plugin de jquery
            $('#tablaNodesPool').DataTable(
                    {
                        "lengthMenu": [[150, 75, 10, -1], [150, 75, 10, "All"]]         
                    }           
            );
            spinner.stop();
            document.getElementById('poolLegend').innerHTML=pool;
          }
        },
        error : function(xhr, errmsg) {
            console.log("error en funcion getMiembrosSnmp " + errmsg); 
            spinner.stop();
        }
    });
```

and apparently since DisplayTags was rendering it during runtime, the div did not exist at the moment the funcion was called, so I needed to wait until DisplayTags rendered the table for the div to exist. I moved the `document.getElementById('controlPools').style.display='none';`
to a point where I knew the table was rendered and it seemed to fix the problem.

This change fixed it:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url  : "ControlNodesPoolAct.action",
        data : {"pool": pool},
        success : function(result){
          if (result != null && result.length > 0){
            var aux = $("#tabs-11"); 
            aux.html(result);
            //inicializamos la tabla con el plugin de jquery
            $('#tablaNodesPool').DataTable(
                    {
                        "lengthMenu": [[150, 75, 10, -1], [150, 75, 10, "All"]]         
                    }           
            );
            spinner.stop();
            document.getElementById('controlPools').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('poolLegend').innerHTML=pool;
          }
        },
        error : function(xhr, errmsg) {
            console.log("error en funcion getMiembrosSnmp " + errmsg); 
            spinner.stop();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Tiles has nothing to do on client side, so if you doing something with JS code you already working with DOM, but this document could be rendered using tiles result. Anyway it will change nothing but the proper style that you need to modify to show/hide some html content using some JS function

**To Hide:**

```
document.getElementById('controlPools').style.display='none';
```

**To show:**

```
document.getElementById('controlPools').style.display='block';
```